# ¿Porque surge la excepción "java.lang.ClassCastException" al realizar una consulta a base de datos con JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, soap

Buen día, estoy realizando un proyecto de prueba acerca de servicios web con SOAP y JPA utilizando el objeto "EntityManager" para crear una consulta por nombre con el metodo "createNamedQuery, el problema surge al momento en el que yo intento obtener mi resultado y castearlo a mi entidad en el proyecto, a continuación muestro el proceso de consulta que realizo:

```
EntityManager em = ef.createEntityManager();
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Alumno.findById", Alumno.class);
query.setParameter("id",1);
Alumno alumnoX = (Alumno) query.getSingleResult();
```

Mi entidad Alumno fue auto generada por Netbeans y esta creada de la siguiente manera:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alumno")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumno.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Alumno a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumno.findById", query = "SELECT a FROM Alumno a WHERE a.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumno.findByNombre", query = "SELECT a FROM Alumno a WHERE a.nombre = :nombre"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumno.findByApellidoM", query = "SELECT a FROM Alumno a WHERE a.apellidoM = :apellidoM"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Alumno.findByApellidoP", query = "SELECT a FROM Alumno a WHERE a.apellidoP = :apellidoP")})
public class Alumno implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "NOMBRE")
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name = "apellidoM")
    private String apellidoM;
    @Column(name = "apellidoP")
    private String apellidoP;

    @Column(name = "edad")
    private int edad;
    
    public Alumno() {
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    
    
    
    public Alumno(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidoM() {
        return apellidoM;
    }

    public void setApellidoM(String apellidoM) {
        this.apellidoM = apellidoM;
    }

    public String getApellidoP() {
        return apellidoP;
    }

    public void setApellidoP(String apellidoP) {
        this.apellidoP = apellidoP;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Alumno)) {
            return false;
        }
        Alumno other = (Alumno) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "service.Alumno[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
    
}
```

El error que se muestra en consola en especifico es:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: service.Alumno cannot be cast to service.Alumno

No logro entender porque el resultado obtenido en la consulta no logra ser casteado con mi entidad, he revisado que todos los atributos en la entidad concuerden con los atributos en la tabla de la base de datos. Estoy realmente confundido ya que la consola indica que un tipo no puede ser casteado a su mismo tipo.

Comment: Podrías colocar el stacktrace completo como parte de la pregunta?

Comment: Intente tipear el `Query`, algo así `Query<Alumno> query = em.createNamedQuery("Alumno.findById", Alumno.class);` y quite el `cast` : `Alumno alumnoX = query.getSingleResult();`

Comment: Lo más probable que ocurra aquí es que tengas dos clases diferentes Alumno, que no están relacionadas entre sí. pero no se puede saber con la información que has agregado, deberíamos ver las clases completas.
Otra posibilidad es que la misma clase se cargue a través de classloaders diferentes, por lo tanto para la JVM son clases totalmente diferentes. Pero eso tampoco se puede saber sin más contexto.

Answer (score 1):

Pueden ser varios motivos, existen Alumnos con id 1?

Prueba esto

```
public Alumno getAlumno(int alumnoId){
    EntityManager em = ef.createEntityManager();

  try{
   return (Alumno) em.createNamedQuery("Alumno.findById",Alumno.class)
              .setParameter("id",alumnoId)
              .getSingleResult();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Pero asegurate que Alumno.class que estás indicando en el namedQuery sea el entity que creaste con netbeans.

Saludos

Comment: Créeme que he recurrido a un sin fin de soluciones y ninguna ha funcionado, parece ser que realmente el culpable es el manejo de "Cache" las entidades de JPA son almacenadas en el Cache para poder crear la persistencia, tal parece que existe una entidad vieja en el servidor la cual se reconoce como diferente al momento de realizar el casteo con mi entidad actual. Desconozco como puedo dar solución a esto.